# grpc client completion queue not shutting down

Tags: grpc

My code performs the following:

1)Create grpc channel

2)start monitoring completion queue in a different thread

3)Issue shutdown on completion queue

After executing step 3, I expect "(cq.Next(&tag, &ok)" to return false as there are no pending events with above 3 steps. But it is observed that "(cq.Next(&tag, &ok)" never returns false. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks,
Ikshu

Answer (score 0):

In order to get channel state notification, a tag was being added to the queue and that use to always post some events. so the cq->next() never returned false. I fixed this issue by achieving same functionality by using already existing standard API for channel state. So closing the bug.